# Is sparking in the motor of my drill a concern?

Tags: tools, electric-motor, hardware

There is a slight sparkling in my drill. What could be the reason? I received a product and checked for first time by plugging it into the socket. I wonder whether it is common or a serious problem.

Comment: Like this??? https://youtu.be/lG5VFtdKDAA

Comment: Agree with Tyson - could just be normal arcing from the brushes of the motor, but its hard to tell from your limited description.

Comment: Does it *always* spark or only when the drill is spinning? If there is sparking even when the motor is not spinning, there is a serious fault.

Comment: If you're working around flammable vapors, it's a very serious problem. But working around flammable vapors is always a serious problem. Otherwise, it's probably normal.

Answer (score 4):

If the motor has brushes some arcing is normal even with high quality equipment, cheaper models usually have more arcs that are visible because the armature is usually rougher. You may notice a decrease in the quantity of arcs as the brushes seat to the armature, I regularly dust my brushed motors with dry compressed air to reduce buildup and on big motors. Usually higher voltage this reduces the chance of flash over that can do a fair amount of damage. + for both comments.

Comment: Most drill motors use universal motors and they have brushes as Ed points out. A small amount of arcing is normal for these types of motors.

Comment: My wife's Ryobi drill sparks a lot, with no problems.